# Water Ball Explosion

Tags: fluid-simulation

I'm trying to do a fluid "explosion" but with water. I initially thought to try the flipfluid addon which sort of worked, but there is no way to add a lifetime to the fluid. So basically I can do an explosion ball of fluid, but it never "dies" Is there a way to do what I want with the native fluid in blender. I see there are inflows and outflows, but not seeing any kind of particle or fluid lifetime.

Comment: It would seem that you want an explosion with water-drops/clumps ...?   Are you saying that you want the water-drops/clumps to evaporate (die)?  Why wouldn't they just fall onto a kill plane (disappear through the domain bottom)?  If you could elaborate (or portray this) in your question (please "Edit"), it would be helpful.

Comment: Edit to explain why "Domain >> Border Collision >> Bottom (disabled)" would not achieve your goal?

Comment: The simulation is at zero gravity, so nothing "falls." I need it to explode and stay in the center of the frame and then have the particles die.